# Calculation of a strange series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to find an expression for:
$$S(N)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^{N}k^n}?$$

For $N=1$ we have

$$S(1) = \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1 + k} = \displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k}$$

which is the (divergent) harmonic series. Thus, $S (1) = \infty$.

For $N=2$ this sum is:
$$S(2)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+k+k^2}$$
which can be expressed as:
$$S(2)=-1+\frac{1}{3}\sqrt 3 \pi \tanh(\frac{1}{2}\pi\sqrt 3)\approx 0.798$$

For $N=3$ we have:
$$S(3)=\frac{1}{4}\Psi(I)+\frac{1}{4I}\Psi(I)-\frac{1}{4I}\pi\coth(\pi)+\frac{1}{4}\pi\coth(\pi)+\frac{1/}{4}\Psi(1+I)-\frac{1}{4I}\Psi(1+I)-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\gamma \approx 0.374$$

Comment: The only thing I can find, using Mathematica, is that the plot of $\frac{1}{x}+1$ looks like the plot of $S_0(\text{Floor}(x))$..

Comment: I love these questions. (+1)

Comment: You write "for $N = 3$", but do not introduce the symbol prior to that. What the heck is $N$?

Comment: @Rod, I had the same thought. I think OP means what is later on referred to as $S_0(N)$. But it would be nice of OP to edit so it makes sense.

Comment: Yes sorry. I don't have defined N.

Comment: I edited the question quite excessively to make it (imo) better to read. Please check if you agree.

Comment: I'm outside and currently unable to try a solution, but I guess that we can make a partial fraction decomposition and use digamma identity to obtain a closed form involving digamma functions.

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra: honestly, I wondered your question some months ago, but I gave up thinking of it since it seemed too cumbersome. I'd be very glad to see a solution for it.

Comment: @Simon Markett: The edited question is correct

Comment: This sum can always be rewritten, for finite $N$, as $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1-k}{1-k^{N+1}}$$ but remains difficult as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perform a partial fraction decomposition:
$$
  \frac{1}{p(k)} = \frac{1}{1+k+\cdots+k^{n-1}} = \frac{1}{ \prod_{m=1}^{n-1}\left(k-\exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right)\right)} = \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k-\exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right)} \frac{1}{p^\prime\left(\exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right)\right)}
$$
Now:
$$
  p^\prime\left(z\right) = \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} m z^{m-1} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} z^{m} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z} \frac{1-z^n}{1-z} = \frac{z-z^n (n-z(n-1))}{z (1-z)^2}
$$
Therefore, using $z^n=1$ for $z=\exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right)$:
$$
c_m := \frac{1}{p^\prime\left(\exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right)\right)} = \frac{1}{n} \exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right) \left( \exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right) - 1 \right) = \frac{1}{n} \exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right) \left( \exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right) - 1 \right) 
$$
We thus have, and using $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} c_m = 0$:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{p(k)} &=& \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{c_m}{k-\exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right)} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} c_m \left(\frac{1}{k-\exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right)} - \frac{1}{k+1}\right) \\ &=&  -\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} c_m \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k-\exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right)}\right) \\ &=&  -\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} c_m \left( \gamma + \psi\left(-\exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right)\right)\right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Again, making use of $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} c_m = 0$ we arrive at:
$$
 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+k+\cdots+k^{n-1}} = \sum_{m=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n} \exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right) \left(1- \exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right) \right)  \cdot  \psi\left(-\exp\left(i \frac{2 \pi}{n} m \right)\right)
$$
where $\psi(x)$ denotes the [digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function).

Comment: Hmm, I'm 2 minutes late, and the contents are almost identical. Maybe I should erase my answer…… OTL

Comment: I do not think there is any need to delete your answer.

Comment: Let $p(k) = 1+k+\cdots+k^{n-1}$. Then $(1-k) p(k) = 1-k^n$, thus $n-1$ roots of $p(k)$ are also roots of $1=k^{n}$.

Comment: @ Sasha: obvious, I know. I deleted my comment before you replied.

Comment: @Sasha, Thanks. I just thought that StackExchange has stringent rules on possible duplication.

Comment: @sos440 Answers are slightly different, although they use the same tactics. I thought SE's rules on possible duplication refer to exact duplicate questions, and copied answers. I do not think it pertains to a situation like this.

Comment: @Chris'ssister Do you the partial fraction decomposition formula? Suppose $p(x)$ is a polynomial whose roots $\alpha_k$ are all simple. Now consider residues of $c_k = \operatorname{Res}_{x=\alpha_k} 1/p(x)$ at $x = \alpha_k$ for each root. Since $1/p(z)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} c_k/(z-\alpha_k)$ are both rational functions, with same poles and same residues, they must be equal.

Answer (score 3):

Let $T(N) = S(N-1)$. Then

$$ \begin{align*}T(n) 
&= 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{n-1}+k^{n-2}+\cdots+k+1} \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{k - 1}{k^n - 1} \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{\omega_l (\omega_l - 1)}{k - \omega_l}  \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{\omega_l (\omega_l - 1)}{k + 2 - \omega_l},
\end{align*}$$

where $\omega_l = \exp\left(\tfrac{2\pi l i}{n}\right)$. Since

$$ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \omega_l (\omega_l - 1) = 0, $$

we may write

$$ \begin{align*}T(n) 
&= 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \omega_l (\omega_l - 1) \left( \frac{1}{k + 2 - \omega_l} - \frac{1}{k+1} \right) \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \omega_l (\omega_l - 1) \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{k + 2 - \omega_l} - \frac{1}{k+1} \right) \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \omega_l (\omega_l - 1) \left( \gamma + \psi_0 (2 - \omega_l) \right) \\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \omega_l (\omega_l - 1) \psi_0 (2 - \omega_l).
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
S(N)=1+\frac1{N+1}+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\left(\zeta((N+1)k-1)-\zeta((N+1)k)\right)
$$

Comment: This expands on @Jon's comment on the main question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an  approach using Mellin transforms to  enrich the collection
of solutions. Write

$$S(N) = 1 + \frac{1}{N+1} + \sum_{k\ge 2} \frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^N k^n}
= 1 + \frac{1}{N+1} + \sum_{k\ge 2} \frac{k-1}{k^{N+1}-1}
\\= 1 + \frac{1}{N+1} + \sum_{k\ge 2} \frac{k}{k^{N+1}-1}
- \sum_{k\ge 2} \frac{1}{k^{N+1}-1}.$$

There are two harmonic sums with  the same base function here which we
now evaluate.

Introduce $$S_1(x, M) = \sum_{k\ge 2} \frac{1}{(xk)^M-1}
\quad\text{and}\quad S_2(x, M) = \sum_{k\ge 2} \frac{k}{(xk)^M-1}$$
so that we are interested in $S_2(1, N+1)-S_1(1, N+1).$

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have for $k\ge 2$ that 
(do $S_1$ first as $S_2$ will follow)
$$\lambda_k = 1, \quad \mu_k = k 
\quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = \frac{1}{x^M-1}.$$

We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$ which is
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^M-1} x^{s-1} dx.$$
We take $M =  N+1 > 2$ since the sum from  the beginning diverges when
$N=1.$

The  fundamental strip  of this Mellin transform is
$\langle 0,M\rangle.$ We will in fact use $\langle 0, M-1\rangle$

Now to  evaluate this (seemingly  divergent) transform we use  a slice
contour with  the bottom side of  the slice aligned  with the positive
real axis  and the  origin. The  angle of the  slice is  $2\pi/M.$ The
radius of the slice is $R$ and we let it go to infinity so that we can
easily  see  the contribution  from  the  arc  that connects  the  two
straight  sides  vanishes  by  the  ML bound  because  its  length  is
$\Theta(R)$ and  the integrand is  $$\Theta(1/R^M\times R^{(M-1)-1}) =
\Theta(1/R^2).$$

We will  be integrating  through the poles  at $x=1$  and $x=\exp(2\pi
i/M),$  thereby picking  up half  the residues  from these  poles. The
integral along  the horizontal  side $\Gamma_1$ of  the slice  is our
transform $g^*(s)$.  The contribution  from the arc call it $\Gamma_2$
vanishes.   Along   the  slanted  side  call  it   $\Gamma_3$  we  put
$x=\exp(2\pi i/M)t$ obtain the following integral:

$$\int_{\Gamma_3} \frac{1}{x^M-1} x^{s-1} dx
\\= \exp(2\pi i/M)
\int_\infty^0 \frac{1}{(\exp(2\pi i/M) t)^M-1} 
(\exp(2\pi i/M) t)^{s-1} dt
\\ = - \exp(2\pi i/M)
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t^M-1} 
(\exp(2\pi i/M) t)^{s-1} dt
\\= - \exp(2\pi i \times s/M)
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t^M-1} t^{s-1} dt =
- \exp(2\pi i \times s/M) \times g^*(s).$$

Putting it all together we have for $g^*(s)$ that
$$g^*(s) = \left(1-e^{2\pi i \times s/M}\right)
= \pi i
\left(
\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{1}{x^M-1} x^{s-1}; x=1\right)+
\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{1}{x^M-1} x^{s-1}; x=\exp(2\pi i/M)\right)
\right).$$

These poles are  simple and may be evaluated  with a single derivative
which gives $1/(M x^{M-1})$ and produces
$$ \pi i 
\left(\frac{1}{M} + 
\frac{1}{M \exp(2\pi i/M)^{M-1}} 
\exp(2\pi i \times (s-1)/M)\right).$$
This is
$$\frac{\pi i}{M}
\left(1 + \exp(2\pi i \times (s-1-(M-1))/M)\right)
\\= \frac{\pi i}{M}
\left(1 + \exp(2\pi i \times (s-M)/M)\right)
\\= \frac{\pi i}{M}
\left(1 + \exp(2\pi i \times s/M)\right).$$
Returning to $g^*(s)$ we finally obtain
$$g^*(s) = \frac{\pi i}{M}
\frac{1 + e^{2\pi i \times s/M}}{1-e^{2\pi i \times s/M}}
= \frac{\pi}{M}
\frac{i(e^{-\pi i \times s/M} + e^{\pi i \times s/M})}
{e^{-\pi i \times s/M}-e^{\pi i \times s/M}}
= - \frac{\pi}{M} \cot(\pi s/M).$$

It  follows that  the Mellin  transform $Q_1(s)$  of the  harmonic sum
$S_1(x,M)$ is given by

$$Q_1(s) = - \frac{\pi}{M} \cot(\pi s/M) (-1+\zeta(s))
\\ \text{because}\\
\sum_{k\ge 2} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\sum_{k\ge 2} \frac{1}{k^s}
= -1+\zeta(s)$$
for $\Re(s) > 1.$

Similarly  the Mellin  transform $Q_2(s)$  of the  harmonic sum
$S_2(x,M)$ is given by

$$Q_2(s) = - \frac{\pi}{M} \cot(\pi s/M) (-1+\zeta(s-1))
\\ \text{because}\\
\sum_{k\ge 2} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\sum_{k\ge 2} k \times \frac{1}{k^s}
= -1+\zeta(s-1)$$
for $\Re(s) > 2.$

The Mellin inversion integral for the first one is
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty} Q_1(s)/x^s ds$$
which we evaluate  by shifting it to the right  for an expansion about
infinity. For the second one we get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{5/2-i\infty}^{5/2+i\infty} Q_2(s)/x^s ds$$

Now  note  that  the first  pole  to  the  right  of the  abscissa  of
convergence is at $s=M$ and since $M\ge 3>5/2>3/2$ we may in fact join
these  two inversion integrals  and write

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{5/2-i\infty}^{5/2+i\infty} 
(Q_2(s)-Q_1(s))/x^s ds$$
which is 
(the minus sign disappears because we are integrating clockwise in the
right half-plane)
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{5/2-i\infty}^{5/2+i\infty} 
\frac{\pi}{M} \cot(\pi s/M) (\zeta(s-1)-\zeta(s))/x^s ds.$$
Observe that
$$\mathrm{Res}\left(\cot(\pi s/M); s=qM\right) = \frac{M}{\pi}$$
with $q$ an integer.

Collecting the  residues at the  poles at $s  = qM$ in the  right half
plane and setting $x=1$ we obtain the convergent series for
$S_2(1, M)-S_1(1, M)$

$$\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{\pi}{M} \frac{M}{\pi} (\zeta(qM-1)-\zeta(qM))
= \sum_{q\ge 1} (\zeta(qM-1)-\zeta(qM)).$$

Returning  to $N$  and the  sum  we started  with we  can confirm  the
earlier result that
$$S(N) = 1 + \frac{1}{N+1} 
+ \sum_{q\ge 1} (\zeta(q(N+1)-1)-\zeta(q(N+1))).$$