# Limit of a recursive sequence $s_n = (1-\frac{1}{4n^2})s_{n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have $$s_1 = 1, s_n = (1-\frac{1}{4n^2})s_{n-1}.$$

I see that its limit exists, but cannot figure out what the limit is. How do I find its limit?

The only way I used (know) is:
$$\lim s_n = \lim s_{n+1}$$
But here, I am just getting $L = L$.

Also, when I program this sequence on computer it's approaching to $0.636619...$ and Wolfram Alpha is giving me complicated recurrence equation solution.

Comment: I sense a disturbance in the force:http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+%281-1%2F%284n%5E2%29%29+from+n%3D1+to+infinity

Comment: Isn't this just the reciprocal of the Wallis Product without the first term?

Comment: If you want your answer to be $0.636619$, I believe that it should say $s_0 = 1$, not $s_1 = 1$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume that $s_0=1$, then
$$
s_n=\frac{((2n)!)^2\,(2n+1)}{2^{4n}\,(n!)^4}.
$$
Stirling equivalent
$$
k!\sim\sqrt{2\pi k}\,k^k\,\mathrm e^{-k},
$$
then yields
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n=\frac2\pi\approx0.63662.
$$
If $s_1=1$ instead of $s_1=\frac34$, then $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}s_n=\frac43\cdot\frac2\pi.$$

Comment: How did you get the first equation ?

Comment: Hello ? How do you justify the first equation ?

Comment: Yes, it'd be great if you could show how to get the first equation.

Comment: @BekAbdik One simply factors as many factorials and powers of $2$ as possible from the product of $1-1/(4k^2)=(2k-1)(2k+1)/(4k^2)$ from $k=1$ to $n$. Did you try yourself?

Answer (score 3):

There is a harmonic sum hiding here which we now examine in more detail.

Introduce $$P = \prod_{n\ge 1} \left(1-\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)$$
so that 
$$ S= \log P = \sum_{n\ge 1} \log\left(1-\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)$$

The sum term may be evaluated by inverting its Mellin
transform. Put
$$S(x) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \log\left(1-\frac{1}{4(xn)^2}\right)$$
so that we are interested in $S(1).$

Recall the harmonic sum identity
$$\mathfrak{M}\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \lambda_k g(\mu_k x);s\right) =
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} \right) g^*(s)$$
where $g^*(s)$ is the Mellin transform of $g(x).$

In the present case we have
$$\lambda_k = 1, \quad \mu_k = k 
\quad \text{and} \quad
g(x) = \log\left(1-\frac{1}{4x^2}\right).$$

We need the Mellin transform $g^*(s)$ of $g(x)$ which is
$$\int_0^\infty \log\left(1-\frac{1}{4x^2}\right) x^{s-1} dx
\\ = \left[\log\left(1-\frac{1}{4x^2}\right) 
\frac{x^s}{s}\right]_0^\infty
+ 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x(1-4 x^2)} \frac{x^s}{s} dx
\\ = \frac{2}{s} 
\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1-4 x^2} x^{s-1} dx.$$

The fundamental  strip of  the term from  the integration by  parts is
$\langle0,  2\rangle,$ which is  also the  fundamental strip  of the
second Mellin transform, call it $h^*(s)$ of $h(x).$

This transform  has poles at $\pm  1/2$ i.e. two  poles on the
real line.  We  will be using a semicircular contour  of radius $R$ in
the  upper  half  plane with  $R$  going  to  infinity to evaluate this transform. 
We  put  small
semicircular  indentations  around  the  two poles.   These  are  both
counterclockwise  and pick  up half  the  residue at  that point.  The
integral on the negative real line is
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 h(x) x^{s-1} dx
= - \int_\infty^0 h(-x) (-x)^{s-1} dx
\\= e^{\pi i (s-1)} \int_0^\infty h(x) x^{s-1} dx
= - e^{\pi i s} h^*(s).$$

This yields for $h^*(s)$ that
$$h^*(s) \left(1-e^{\pi i s}\right)
\\= \frac{1}{2}\times 2\pi i
\left(\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1-4 x^2} x^{s-1}; x=-1/2\right)
+\mathrm{Res}\left(\frac{1}{1-4 x^2} x^{s-1}; x=1/2\right)\right)
\\=\pi i
\left(\frac{1}{4} (-1/2)^{s-1}
- \frac{1}{4} (1/2)^{s-1}\right).$$
This gives for $h^*(s)$ that
$$h^*(s) =
\pi i \frac{1}{4} (1/2)^{s-1} 
\frac{e^{i\pi(s-1)}-1}{1-e^{\pi i s}}
= -\pi i \frac{1}{4} (1/2)^{s-1} 
\frac{1+e^{i\pi s}}{1-e^{\pi i s}}
\\ = -\pi (1/2)^{s+1} 
\frac{i(e^{-i\pi s/2}+e^{i\pi s/2})}{e^{-i\pi s/2}-e^{\pi i s/2}}
= \pi (1/2)^{s+1} \cot(\pi s/2).$$

It follows that the Mellin transform $Q(s)$ of the harmonic sum 
$S(x)$ is given by

$$Q(s) = \frac{2}{s} \pi (1/2)^{s+1} \cot(\pi s/2) \zeta(s)$$
which is
$$ \frac{\pi}{s}\frac{\cot(\pi s/2)}{2^s} \zeta(s)
\quad\text{because}\quad
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{\lambda_k}{\mu_k^s} = 
\sum_{k\ge 1} \frac{1}{k^s}
= \zeta(s)$$
for $\Re(s) > 1.$

The Mellin  inversion integral here  is determined by the  abscissa of
convergence  of  the zeta  function  term  and  is $$\frac{1}{2\pi  i}
\int_{3/2-i\infty}^{3/2+i\infty}  Q(s)/x^s ds$$  which we  evaluate by
shifting it to the right for an expansion about infinity. (In any case
the pole  of the zeta function is  cancled by a zero  of the cotangent
term.)

Collecting  the contributions  from  the poles  at  the even  positive
integers of  the contangent term we get  the sum (with a  minus due to
the shift to the right and setting $x=1$ for the value $S(1)$)

$$-\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{\pi}{2q} \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{\zeta(2q)}{2^{2q}}
= - \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{\zeta(2q)}{q 2^{2q}}.$$
In terms of Bernoulli numbers this becomes
$$ \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^q B_{2q} (2\pi)^{2q}}{2(2q)!} 
\frac{1}{q 2^{2q}}
= \sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{i^{2q} B_{2q} \pi^{2q}}{2q(2q)!}.$$
This is
$$ -\frac{i B_1\pi}{1\times 1!} +
\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{i^q B_q \pi^q}{q\times q!}
\quad\text{or}\quad
\frac{1}{2} i\pi +
\sum_{q\ge 1} \frac{i^q B_q \pi^q}{q\times q!}.$$

Now recall that
$$-1 + \frac{t}{e^t-1} = 
\sum_{q\ge 1} B_q \frac{t^q}{q!}
\quad\text{so that}\quad
-\frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{e^t-1}
= \sum_{q\ge 1} B_q \frac{t^{q-1}}{q!}.$$
Integration of the generating function yields
$$-\log t + \log(e^t-1) - t
= \sum_{q\ge 1} B_q \frac{t^q}{q\times q!}.$$

The left and  the right are zero in  the limit as $t$ goes  to zero so
there  are no  problems with  the  constant that  appeared during  the
integration.

Putting $t=i\pi$ and collecting everything we finally obtain
$$S(1) = \frac{1}{2}\pi i
- \log(i\pi) + \log(-2) - i \pi
\\= \frac{1}{2}\pi i 
- \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi i + \log \pi\right)
+ \left(\log 2 + i\pi\right) - i\pi
= \log\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)$$
and therefore
$$P = \exp\log\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right) =  \frac{2}{\pi}.$$

**Observation.** The reader may well contend that in our last step we have
tacitly chosen  a branch  cut for the  logarithm. The fact  is however
that  the result  does not  depend  on the  sheet. Suppose  we have  a
logarithm that produces arguments in the range $[2\pi, 4\pi).$ We get

$$ \frac{1}{2}\pi i 
- \left(\frac{5}{2} \pi i + \log \pi\right)
+ \left(\log 2 + 3i\pi\right) - i\pi
= \log\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right).$$

For  a  logarithm with  the  cut on  the  positive  imaginary axis  and
argument in $[\pi/2, 5\pi/2)$ we get

$$ \frac{1}{2}\pi i 
- \left(\frac{1}{2} \pi i + \log \pi\right)
+ \left(\log 2 + i\pi\right) - i\pi
= \log\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right).$$

There is another "divergent" Mellin transform with poles on the positive real line at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194096/calculation-of-a-strange-series).

Answer (score 2):

Clearly, the limit of the sequence is equal to $\displaystyle \prod_{n = 2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{4n^2 - 1}{4n^2} \right)$. This is the reciprocal of the Wallis product (without the first term). The Wallis Product is equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ with the first term, $\frac{4}{3}$, so without it it is equal to $\frac{3 \pi}{8}$. Since this is the reciprocal, the desired answer is $\frac{8}{3 \pi}$. (By your program approximation, I suspect you meant to say that $s_0 = 1$ and not $s_1 = 1$, in which case the answer would just be $\frac{2}{\pi}$

One may prove the Wallis Product in many ways, originally by expressing $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ as a polynomial with roots at $\pm n \pi$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. You may read about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{s_{1} = 1\,,\qquad s_{n} = \pars{1 - {1 \over 4n^{2}}}s_{n - 1}\,,\quad n \geq 2
     .\qquad\lim_{n \to \infty}s_{n}: {\large ?}}$

> $$
> s_{n} =\pars{1 - {1 \over 4n^{2}}}\bracks{1 - {1 \over 4\pars{n - 1}^{2}}}
> \ldots \pars{1 - {1 \over 4\times 2^{2}}}s_{1}
> $$

\begin{align}
\ln\pars{s_{n}}&=\overbrace{\ln\pars{s_{1}}}^{\ds{0}}\
+\ \sum_{k = 2}^{n}\ln\pars{1 - {1 \over 4k^{2}}}
=-\sum_{k = 2}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd x \over x + 4k^{2} - 1}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 2}
{1 \over \pars{k + 2 + \root{1 - x}/2}\pars{k + 2 - \root{1 - x}/2}}
\end{align}

> With $\ds{\quad t \equiv \root{1 - x}\quad\imp\quad x = 1 - t^{2}}$:
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#c00000}{\lim_{n \to \infty}\ln\pars{s_{n}}}&
> =-\,{1 \over 4}
> \int_{0}^{1}{\Psi\pars{2 + \root{1 - x}/2} - \Psi\pars{2 - \root{1 - x}/2}
> \over \root{1 - x}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\half\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{%
> \Psi\pars{2 + {t \over 2}} - \Psi\pars{2 - {t \over 2}}}\,\dd t
> =-\left.\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{2 + {t \over 2}}\Gamma\pars{2 - {t \over 2}}}
> \vphantom{\LARGE A}\right\vert_{0}^{1}
> \\[3mm]&=-\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{5 \over 2}\Gamma\pars{3 \over 2}} +\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{2}\Gamma\pars{2}}
> =-\ln\pars{{3 \over 2}\,\Gamma^{2}\pars{3 \over 2}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\ln\pars{{3 \over 2}\,{1 \over 4}\,\Gamma^{2}\pars{\half}}
> =-\ln\pars{3\pi \over 8}=\color{#c00000}{\ln\pars{8 \over 3\pi}}
> \end{align}

Then,
$$
\color{#00f}{\large\lim_{n \to \infty}s_{n} = {8 \over 3\pi}} \approx 0.8488
$$

> $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z}}$ and $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ are the [Gamma and Digamma Functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function), respectively.